# Laravel passing variables from one seed file to another?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have created multiple seed files and my main DatabaseSeeder file looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $name1 = "James";
        $name2 = "Jeff";
        $name3 = "Joe";

        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PersonTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(IndividualTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(HumanTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that UserTableSeeder and PersonTableSeeder gets the variables from my main seeder file? (What I'm really trying to do is use Faker to output random values, but use the same value for each table seeder)

Comment: When you get to `PersonTableSeeder` you will iterate users and create a person for each. This means you only need to generate names in the `PersonTableSeeder`.

Comment: For what i'm trying to do I need some columns to match the same value in  other tables, that's why i'm settings variables outside of the classes. For example i'll have a random number generated, and I want to pass that same number to both `UserTableSeeder` and `PersonTableSeeder`.

Comment: You have to create a person for an user, this user will have the random number.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean sorry. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Maybe have a look at seeding the random number generator in Faker (not the same as seeding the database): https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#seeding-the-generator. Using the same seed will generate the same result on each run.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem, ended up overriding the call() function by adding $extra var and passing it to run() function.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $name1 = "James";
        $name2 = "Jeff";
        $name3 = "Joe";

        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class, $name1);
        $this->call(PersonTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(IndividualTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(HumanTableSeeder::class);
    }

    public function call($class, $extra = null) {
        $this->resolve($class)->run($extra);

        if (isset($this->command)) {
            $this->command->getOutput()->writeln("<info>Seeded:</info> $class");
        }
    }

}
```

and then add $extra to your seeder class

```
// database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php


  /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run($extra = null)
    {
        var_dump($extra);
    }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: As of laravel 8.2 this is not necessary anymore, you can natively pass arguments to the seeders using `$this->callWith(SeederClass::class, ['param1', 'param2']);`

Answer (score 9):

[As of laravel 8.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php#L68) you can pass parameters to seeders natively like so

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $name1 = "James";

        $this->callWith(UserTableSeeder::class, ['name' => $name1]);
        $this->call(PersonTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(IndividualTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(HumanTableSeeder::class);
    }

}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run($name = null)
    {
        var_dump($name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Saved me some hair.

Comment: Funny that they don't mention this in the readme. It's super useful

Comment: Btw there is a small error. In my version of Laravel (8.14.0), you have to change the code, because it results in `null`. Change it to `$this->callWith(UserTableSeeder::class, ['name' => $name1]);` only then ` var_dump($name);` shows you `James`

Comment: @PhilippMochine Corrected

Answer (score 1):

### Laravel 8,X

Here is a combination of all the best answers on that subject were I a prompt to get the values:

```
// DatabaseSeeder.php


    public function run() {
        // example 1: Use directly with inside seeder
        $name     = $this->command->ask( 'Name of first user', 'Jhon Doe' );
        $email    = $this->command->ask( 'Email of first user', 'default@company.com' );
        $password = $this->command->ask( 'Password of  first user', '12345678' );

        User::factory()->create( [
            'name'     => $name,
            'email'    => $email,
            'password' => Hash::make( $password )
        ] );

        // example 2: Pass value to inner-Seeder
        $answer = $this->command->ask( "Do you want to make this user ($name:$email) an admin? (yes/no)", 'Yes' );
        $this->callWith( PermissionSeeder::class, [ 'answer' => $answer ] );
    }
```

```
// PermissionSeeder.php

 public function run( int|string $answer = null ) {
       // ...
        
        $rootID = null;

        if ( isset( $answer ) && ! empty( $answer ) ) {
            if ( is_numeric( $answer ) ) {
                $rootID = (int) $answer;
            } elseif ( is_string( $answer ) && str_starts_with( strtolower( $answer ), 'y' ) ) {
                $rootID = 1;
            }
        }

        echo $rootID ? "User [$rootID] will be elevated to super user" : "[$answer] Ignore  set-user-as-root.";
        echo "";
        if ( $rootID ) {
            $user = User::findOrFail( $rootID );
            $user?->assignRole( 'super-utilisateur' );
        }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Anyone who is also looking for this. Accepted answer will work, but why over complicate such simple things?

Just use constants or globals.

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
define('SEEDING_SIZE', 10);
```

Now in any seeder this will be available as "SEEDING_SIZE".

No extra functions needed.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Comment: Please no.. Don't use globals or constant.. This is terrible design